# No viable alternative at input 'ALLOW'

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

```
@Query("select * from asset_layered_view where client_uuid = :clientUUID and "
    + "site_uuid = :siteUUID and installation_uuid = :installationUUID and "
    + "file_name = :fileName ALLOW FILTERING"
```

While Executing this query I am getting the below error:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 3:33 no viable
>   alternative at input 'ALLOW' (...and
>   installation_uuid=de8afb7f-8791-4069-8e37-e4704c6f610b and
>   file_name=[download_media].png...)

Comment: Did you forget the closing double quote after ALLOW FILTERING?

Comment: Also it would be useful to add to question the table description and some sample data

Comment: My guess is that your are forgetting the quotes for file_name since this one is text.

Comment: Your query should be something like select * from asset_layered_view where client_uuid = uuid and file_name='download_media.png'. I omitted siteuuid and instalation_uuid since they where not important for the sake of example.

Comment: Sort of related...   But does this query need to perform well?  If so, don't use ALLOW FILTERING.  Ever.